# What is wrong with this t-sql syntax?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to run sql written in Access on sql server. The query is throwing a syntax error on line 4:

```
UPDATE mytablename SET 
table.[Specimen Collection Date 1] = 
IIf(
[Specimen Collection Date 2] Is Not Null,   //incorrect syntax near is
[Specimen Collection Date 2],
IIf([Specimen Collection Date 2] Is Null,[Specimen Collection Date 3] Is Not Null))
```

It seems like a valid column name `[Speciment Collection Date]` seems like a valid [expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188795.aspx).

What am I missing?

Comment: Which version of SQL server are you running it on?  It looks like `IIF` was introduced in SQL Server 2012

Comment: I'm pretty sure that column names can have spaces in them.

Comment: I think you're probably looking for [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx), or [`Nz`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/nz-function-HA001228890.aspx), but that's not a direct answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no IIf in sql. Look up the `case when` tsql convention.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Comment: Okay my bad. I'm not up on 2012.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include the TABLE in your column definition.  The DB knows what table it is from your "Update TABLE" statement.

Comment: I don't think you need to include TABLE in  "set TABLE.ColumnName".  Try removing it and see if that helps.